# ¿Cómo obtener el porcentaje de carga de el evento Window.onload de Javascript para un ProgressBar?

Tags: javascript

Quiero realizar un **ProgressBar** de un sitio web.

Lo único que tengo hasta este punto es la referencia de haber hecho algo similar utilizando una animación gif y con el **handler** `window.onload` me aparece la página completa al haberse cargado.

Pero ¿Cómo puedo obtener el progreso de carga de la página?

Comment: Primero, debes mostrar que es lo que tienes, sino se tiende asumir que no has hecho nada, y seria mejor mandarte un link donde enseñan a hacer progress bar - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/

Comment: El progressbar lo tengo, mi duda es como combinarlo para que muestre el tiempo de carga real de mi sitio web

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
let width = 100,
    perfData = window.performance.timing, // The PerformanceTiming interface represents timing-related performance information for the given page.
    EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
    time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

// Loadbar Animation
$(".loadbar").animate({
  width: width + "%"
}, time);

// Loadbar Glow Animation
$(".glow").animate({
  width: width + "%"
}, time);

// Percentage Increment Animation
let PercentageID = $("#precent"),
    start = 0,
    end = 100,
    durataion = time;
    animateValue(PercentageID, start, end, durataion);
    
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  
  let range = end - start,
      current = start,
      increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
      stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
      obj = $(id);
    
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    current += increment;
    $(obj).text(current + "%");
      //obj.innerHTML = current;
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}

// Fading Out Loadbar on Finised
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.preloader-wrap').fadeOut(300);
}, time);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
  background-color: #222;
}

.preloader-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  z-index : 2; 
}

.percentage {
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size : 15px;
}

.loader,
.percentage{
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 500px; 
  border: 2px solid #69AF23;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  margin : auto; 
}
.loader:after,
.percentage:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.trackbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.99;
}

.loadbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg, 
    #008737, 
    #008737 10px, 
    #69AF23 10px,
    #69AF23 20px
  ); /* Stripes Background Gradient */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px #008737; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: flicker 5s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.glow {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 10px #008737;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  animation: animation 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0.86;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

.wrap { 
  background-image : url(http://wallpaperfx.com/view_image/little-girls-1600x900-wallpaper-5569.jpg);
  background-position: left top; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative;  
  z-index : 1; 
}

.copyrights { 
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.copyrights a { color: orange; text-decoration: none; }
.copyrights a:hover { color : #fff; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader-wrap">
  <div class="percentage" id="precent"></div>
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="trackbar">
      <div class="loadbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="glow"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <span class="copyrights">Image taken from: <a href="http://www.wallpaperfx.com">wallpaperfx.com</a></span>
</div>
```

referencia:

https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/MwppEB

una libreria:

https://github.com/hdodov/realprogress.js

Comment: Lo probaré, para dar por respondida la pregunta